# Why are the LDP installed LSPs not seen in the output of "show mpls lsp" in Junos?

Tags: juniper, mpls, ldp

I have established a LDP session between routers `r1`(`lo0.0` has `192.168.1.1` configured) and `r4`(`lo0.0` has `192.168.1.4` configured). According to `show route table inet.3 192.168.1.4` in `r1` the BGP prefixes with the next-hop of `192.168.1.4` would use MPLS:

```
root@r1> show route table inet.3 192.168.1.4

inet.3: 4 destinations, 6 routes (4 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

192.168.1.4/32     *[LDP/9] 01:19:20, metric 1
                    > to 65.115.1.2 via ge-0/0/1.0, Push 300048

root@r1>
```

However, when I check the ingress LSPs, then there is no LSP to `192.168.1.4`:

```
root@r1> show mpls lsp ingress
Ingress LSP: 3 sessions
To              From            State Rt P     ActivePath       LSPname
192.168.1.5     192.168.1.1     Up     0 *     ERO-through-R3   R1-to-R5
192.168.1.3     192.168.1.1     Up     0 *                      sub_lsp_to_R3
192.168.1.5     192.168.1.1     Up     0 *                      sub_lsp_to_R5
Total 3 displayed, Up 3, Down 0

root@r1>
```

Does the `show mpls lsp` in Junos show only static and RSVP LSPs? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the `show mpls lsp` in Junos show only static and RSVP LSPs? Or am I missing something here?

It's counter intuitive, but you're correct, only RSVP LSPs are shown with `show mpls lsp`.  It's basically tied to the fact that you configure RSVP LSPs under `[protocols mpls]`, whereas with LDP, you don't.

Your best options for LDP are `show ldp sessions`, `show ldp neighbors`, and whatever your favorite variation of `show route` is.